# How to align a Linear Program to the left and right without breaking the numeration in Latex?

Tags: align

Im writing my Master Thesis. Making it short. I have this:

[My Linear Program in Latex so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaFn.png)

Created with this code:

```
\begin{align}
    &\my minimizing function \\
    \nonumber \\
    &\first restriction  & \definition for restriction\\
    &\second restriction & \definition for second restriction
\end{align}
```

But I need this:

[The Program from an actual Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OOoT.png)

I looked everything up. From arrays over nested alignments to special formulas for the header.
I think it should work by adjusting the way `&` works. But i really dont know how. How can I make `&` to not push my numeration of the equations aside?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi an welcome to tex.stackexchange. Could you turn your code into a minimum working example (MWE) so that we can see what is actually not working the way you want it to? See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that]] for some help on that.

Comment: Now its a MWE. Hopefully it helps

Comment: Since you have a “program so far”, please include it in your question.

Comment: The code you're seeing above is exactly what I did. Or i dont get you correctly.

Comment: Do you want after one year one answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the systeme package. It's documentation is somewhat hard to follow, and it has some endearing quirks. But it does the job, typesetting linear programs (or linear systems) beautifully with little work.

Comment: Please provide example code to show how this might work.

Comment: Would be great to get an example here. Because I already looked up the systeme package and it doenst provide an example for my case. I never saw an example of an equation where the restriction of it is pushed to the right but ends before the equation counter.